# Calling jquery function from ascx not working

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ascx, webusercontrol

I'm having a problem with the following situation.

I have an ascx which contains a submit button for a search criteria and I am trying to call a validation function in a js file I've used throughout the site (this is the first time I'm using it in an ascx).

Now I've just tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsAdmin_Generic_SystemValidation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".submitBtn").click(function (e) {
            alert("test");
            alert($.Validate());
            alert("test 2");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The file is being referenced correctly as I am already seeing posts in Firebug that are done by it.

This is the function:

```
jQuery.extend({
Validate: function () {
    var requiredElements = $('.required').length; // Get the number of elements with class required

    $('.required').each(function () {
        // If value of textbox is empty and have not
        // yet been validated then validate all required
        // elements. i.e.
        if (($(this).val() == "") || ($(this).hasClass("validationError")) || ($(this).hasClass("validationAlert")) || ($(this).hasClass("validationOk") == false)) {
            validate($(this));
        }
    });

    if ($('.validationOk').length == requiredElements) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
},
// Another extended function, this function
// is used for pages with the edit-in-place
// feature implemented.
validateElement: function (obj) {
    var elementId = obj.attr("id"); // id of the button clicked.
    var flag = 0;

    if (elementId.toLowerCase() == "paymentmethodid") {
        // Case elementId = paymentMethodId then check all the 
        // elements with css class starting with openStorage
        var requiredElements = $(document).find("input[class*='openStorage']").length; // Get the number of elements with css class starting with openStorage

        // Loop through all the elements with css class containing
        // openStorage abd validate each element.
        $(document).find("input[class*='openStorage']").each(function () {
            if (($(this).val() == "") || ($(this).hasClass("validationError")) || ($(this).hasClass("validationAlert"))) {
                validate($(this));
            }

            if ($(this).hasClass("validationOk")) {
                flag++;
            } else if (($(this).hasClass("validationError")) || ($(this).hasClass("validationAlert"))) {
                flag--;
            }
        });

        // If all elements are valid return true else return false
        if (flag == requiredElements) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (elementId.toLowerCase() == "registeredfortax") {
        if (($('.TaxRegistrationNumber').val() == "") || ($('.TaxRegistrationNumber').hasClass("validationError")) || ($('.TaxRegistrationNumber').hasClass("validationAlert"))) {
            validate($('.TaxRegistrationNumber'));
        }

        if ($('.TaxRegistrationNumber').hasClass("validationOk")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        var elementClass = "." + elementId;

        if (($(elementClass).val() == "") || ($(elementClass).hasClass("validationError")) || ($(elementClass).hasClass("validationAlert")) || ($(elementClass).hasClass("validationOk") == false)) {
            validate($(elementClass));
        }

        if ($(elementClass).hasClass("validationOk") && ($(elementClass).hasClass("required"))) {
            return true;
        } else if ($(elementClass).hasClass("required") == false) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
});
```

Now at first I was getting "Validate() is not a function" in firebug. Since I did that alert testing, I am getting the first alert, then nothing with no errors.

Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the full code of the Validate() function, and also your html? Also, when you call $(".submitBtn"). I guess it means you have several buttons throughout your app (the Submit button on your .ascx being one of them) that have a .submitBtn class?

Comment: I've added the code of the whole Validation.

I have a lot of buttons that are using this validation, but that script I posted is in the ascx, other buttons are using a central Javascript.

I was trying to use this button first:
<asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" Style="margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px;" runat="server" Text="Refresh" class="button submitBtn" />

But a regular html button still is giving out the same problems:

<input type="button" value="Search" class="submitBtn button" />

Comment: I see this line: validate($(this)) appear several times, but no associated function. Is there code missing? Are you able to set a breakpoint in IE and follow the execution into the extend method?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the extend method properly? ...
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: Ah yes. There was some code outside the code block. I have edited it so that it is included.